# Pycharm underlines absolute import, but it works fine

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have path server->api(folder), manage.py.
Pycharm underlines my absolute import `from api.views import create_user` but it works! If i type like `from server.api.views import create_user` pycharm does not underline, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm has option called 'Mark Directory as' when you right click your specific directory in the Project tree.

Try to mark 'Server' folder as 'Sources root' and it should work fine.

Comment: I marked server folder, which contains ```manage.py``` as Source root, edit the answer, pls, thx

Comment: Use first import 'from api.views import create_user'
or try marking 'server' as Sources root

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue to for a long time and was really annoyed with the following simplified folder structure. I had to do like @token said, but couldn't get it to work. Turns out I had to mark the `project` folder as **sources root** in PyCharm and that solved all the import issues!

````
└── project name
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    └── project
        ├── .dockerignore
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── app
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── main.py
        │   └── models
        │       └── __init__.py
        ├── db
        │   └── Dockerfile
        └── requirements.txt
    ```
````